# Adding httpClient to Azure Function in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions

It seems like a trivial thing, but I have created an Azure Function in the Azure Portal and I want to add a httpClient object to it in order to fire off a http request at the interval set in the function. I wanted to go the Azure Portal route, because these are going to be very simple functions that shouldn't require needing to have any development in a code editor or IDE.

The code that is created looks like this:

```
using System;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
}
```

Now as I search through the internet, I see a lot of documentation on older versions of Azure Functions, but I'm not seeing much at all regarding how to deal with this style of C# (I'm assuming it's because it's a `.csx` file) in relation to creating Azure Functions.

My question is, how would I add an httpClient to this Run.csx file? Specifically, using a httpClientFactory.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

> how to deal with this style of C# (I'm assuming it's because it's a `.csx` file)

Yes, we can add the code in `.csx` file.

I have taken references from the blob by @[Nicklas Møller Jepsen](https://blog.jepsen.ninja/using-ihttpclientfactory-in-azure-functions) to add HttpClient.

The NuGet Package Required to add `HttpClient` is `Microsoft.Extensions.Http`.

As mentioned in the [MSDOc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp?tabs=functionsv2%2Cfixed-delay%2Cazure-cli#how-csx-works), we can use `#r` to reference a package.

***Ex:***

```cs
#r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc"
```

***Or***

We can upload the package directly using the upload option.

[image]

- You can see the uploaded package in the dropdown.

[image]